# How to handle exceptions in a Jenkins Job DSL seed job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

If I had a Git repository full of Job DSL groovy scripts and a typical seed job e.g.:

```
job('seed') {
    //... scm, triggers etc.
    steps {
        dsl {
            external 'jobs/**/*.groovy'
        }
    }
    //... more config etc.
}
```

what happens if just one of the job dsl scripts throws an exception for some reason, for example:

```
job('deliberate-fail') {
    throw new Exception("Arrrgggghhh")
}
```

Is it possible to handle this exception in the seed job or will the whole seed job fail?

If all but one would work - is it possible for the seed job to record an **UNSTABLE** result rather than **FAILURE**?

I don't really want *one bad apple to spoil the bunch*.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it with simple `try-catch` block?

Comment: That sounds promising.  Would that be inside the specific jobs?  I'm afaid I'm quite new to Groovy and Job DSL so I haven't quite worked out what is possible.If I caught an exception how would I mark the build as unstable?

Comment: I usually put it in a specific job. Using `currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'` should do the job..

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  I'll give that a go.

Comment: Let me know if that helped you. I will add an answer then.

Comment: Thank you Opal.  That really helped, I've added my answer below - but I feel I owe you the reputation points.

Comment: Nevermind ;) Glad you've worked it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Opal's suggestion to use a try-catch, I modifed the job to capture the exception and print an error to the console.

```
job('deliberate-fail') {
    try {
        throw new Exception("Arrrgggghhh")
    } catch (Exception ex){
        println("deliberate-fail job is [UNSTABLE]")
    }
}
```

As I am currently using the [Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) (and not a Jenkins Pipeline script), I don't think Opal's suggestion to use "*currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'*" was available to me.  After a little digging I found I could use the [Text-Finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) to search the console for the "*[UNSTABLE]*" error and change the seed job state accordingly.

```
job('seed-job') {
     steps {
        dsl {
            external '**/*_jobdsl.groovy'
        }
    }
    publishers {
        textFinder(/[UNSTABLE]/, '', true, false, true)
    }    
}
```

A bit convoluted but it seems to work!